# QTP Retrieve code that has already been executed

Tags: reflection, qtp

I'm trying to figure out a way to reflectively look at the code that I've executed in a QTP script.  The idea here is, when I encounter a crash, have a recovery scenario that captures an error message and sends it to QC as a defect.  If I can see the code I've already executed, then I could also include the steps to reproduce the defect, in theory.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Movie recording and playback**

QTP11 (finally) has a feature for demands like that: Take a look at `Tools`, `Options`, `Run`, `Screen capture`. "`Save movie to results`" there allows you to record exactly what happened. The resulting movie is part of the run result, i.e. if you submit a bug with this run result, the movie will be included.

I would not use such a feature because you would have to record the movie always just to have it in case of error. You would end up with big run results that contain movies nobody wants to see, just to have them in the rare cases that an error occurred and a defect is created. *But:*

In this regard, HP has done the job right: You can select in the dialog to save the movie to results only if an error occurs. And, to avoid saving the hole boring part of the test execution that did not contain errors, yet seeing the critical steps that lead to the error, you can specify to keep only the last N kB of the movie so you will always see what lead to the error.

**Option 2: "Macro" recording and playback**

You could, in theory, create your own playback methods for all test objects (registering functions via RegisterUserFunc), and make them save the call info into some data structure before doing the playback step (by calling the original playback function).

Then, still in theory, you could create a nice little playback engine that iterates over that data structure and executes exactly the playback steps that were recorded previously.

I´ve done similar stuff to repeat bundles of playback steps after changing AUT config to iterate a given playback over various configs without changing the code that does the original playback.

But hey, this is quite some work, lots of things can be wrong: The AUT must be in the same intial state upon playback as during "recording of playback". This includes all relevant databases and subsystems of your testing environment. Usually, this is not an easy task in large projects and not worth the trouble (we are talking about re-creating the original initial config just to reproduce one single bug).

**So I suggest you check out the movie feature, i.e. option 1. It does not playback the steps in the AUT, but it shows what happened during the original playback -- exactly.**

Comment: Option 1 is pretty interesting, and covers part of what I'm looking for, but I was hoping to find a way to get the code that had just been run. Since it's been a while since I asked the question, I'll accept your answer.